# Nesting schema in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to create nested products in mongoose schema. And trying to create schema into schema. How to make that, and how after that to get the nested schema ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

reffering to [mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) you can do it like so:

```
  const schema = new Schema({
  name:    String,
  binary:  Buffer,
  living:  Boolean,
  updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  age:     { type: Number, min: 18, max: 65 },
  mixed:   Schema.Types.Mixed,
  _someId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  decimal: Schema.Types.Decimal128,
  array: [],
  ofString: [String],
  ofNumber: [Number],
  ofDates: [Date],
  ofBuffer: [Buffer],
  ofBoolean: [Boolean],
  ofMixed: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
  ofObjectId: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
  ofArrays: [[]],
  ofArrayOfNumbers: [[Number]],
  nested: {
    stuff: { type: String, lowercase: true, trim: true }
  },
  map: Map,
  mapOfString: {
    type: Map,
    of: String
  }
})
```

for example for an object of strings you can use the nested property.